# project_android crashing

Tags: android, android-studio, crash

when i open my project in android studio the app crashes whether it's on my phone connected by cable/wifi or on the emulator i created. I'm not sure if it crashes but it just wont open

I tried restarting my phone, android studio, force stop, etc

Comment: Please update your question with the errors causing the crash. Without errors from the Logcat we can't help.